# Avoiding nested loops when comparing objects in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have been given two pieces of code which were written by different people at different times and both work well individually. It's my job to compare outputs between these two pieces of code. I also need to check that there aren't any errors in certain fields.

Script 1 returns a list of `Script1Object`s, each with their own properties. Similarly, Script 2 returns a list of `Script2Object`s, which are similar to `Script1Object`s but are not identical.

My code does something like this:

```py
script1_list = script1()
script2_list = script2()

for item1 in script1_list:
    for item2 in script2_list:
        if is_match(item1, item2):
            do_matching_action()
            break
        elif is_different_match(item1, item2):
            do_other_matching_action()
            break

    if is_bad(item1):
       do_error_action()
```

where `is_match()` matches on about ten different attributes. For example:

```py
def is_match(item1, item2):
    return item1.name == item2.name and item1.ID == item2.number and item1.description.startswith(item2.desc)
```

and `is_different_match()` and `is_bad()` have a similar set of checks.

This works fine but it can be slow, especially when the first list can have several hundreds of thousands of entries and the second easily has thousands. The code also isn't very modular so I'm hoping that avoiding the double `for` loop would improve the extensibility of the code. I was wondering how this implementation could be improved upon as I'm sure this isn't making the best use of Python's features.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to compare each script1 object against each and every script2object?

Comment: You're right. There should only ever be one match (and that's not something I need to test for) so I can put a ```break``` in there.

Comment: You could convert your objects to `tuples`, for example, and reduce the time complexity to *O(1)* by using a `set` to store tuple representations. But the problem is that your match functions have conditions like `item1.description.startswith(item2.desc)` which makes that hard. Does `item2.desc` have a fixed number of characters?

Comment: slider - Unfortunately not. I've seen anything from zero to several hundred characters.

Comment: Are the ids unique in each list? Can we expect only one item with a certain `ID` in `script1_list` and similarly with a unique `number` in `script2_list`?

Comment: Let me check that one...

Comment: It looks like there can be duplicate ```ID```s in ```script1_list``` items but I can't see anything suggesting that ```number```s for ```script2_list``` items can't be unique.

Comment: And is the id check (`item1.ID == item2.number`) present in all match functions?

Comment: Yes (but not the error-checking one). The only ones that change are date comparisons.

Comment: is `len(script1_list ) == len(script2_list )`?

Comment: That's not something I can assume. They both vary but the first can have several hundreds of thousands of entries and the second easily has thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that matching objects have to have similar ids (`ID` in `Script1Object` and `number` in `Script2Object`), and assuming that `script2_list` items all have unique `number`s, you can create a mapping from `number` to the object using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Then, as you're iterating, you can get a `Script2Object` from the dictionary by its `number` directly (without having to loop through the entire `script2_list`). You can then call each match function on both objects as you were doing before:

```
script1_list = script1()
script2_list = script2()
script2_dict = {obj.number: obj for obj in script2_list}

for item1 in script1_list:
    item2 = script2_dict.get(item1.ID, None)
    if item2 is None: 
        print('no item2 found for this id: ', item1.ID)
        # do something if there's no matching id
    if is_match(item1, item2):
        do_matching_action()
    elif is_different_match(item1, item2):
        do_other_matching_action()

    if is_bad(item1):
       do_error_action()
```

Comment: It took me a little while to work out what this was doing but you've halved the number of ```for``` loops and I think I like it! I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking along the same lines as @slider, but you might like to see my approach.  It uses the same logic of first finding the `ID` in the list from the second script.

The main difference is I have used list comprehension to make the code a bit more compact and to avoid using elif.  It also keeps track of the different matching elements in output lists, in case you need to need to access them later.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, ID, desc):
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.desc = desc


class B(object):
    def __init__(self, name, ID, desc):
        self.name = name
        self.ID = ID
        self.desc = desc

def do_bad(a):
    print('catch some errors here')
    return a

def do_matching_action(a):
    print('Found match with name = {0}, ID  = {1}, and desc = {2}'.format(a.name, a.ID, a.desc))    
    return a      

item1 = A('name', 1, 'weird_desc')
item2 = A('name', 2, 'weird_desc')
item3 = A('name', 3, 'not_same_desc')
item4 = A('name', 4, 'wei')
item5 = B('name', 1, 'weird_desc')

list1 = [item1, item2, item1, item2, item5]
list2 = [item3, item4, item1, item4, item1]


id_dict = {a.ID: a for a in list2}
common_objects = [a for a in list1 if a.ID in id_dict.keys()]
uncommon_objects = [a for a in list1 if a.ID not in id_dict.keys()]

#peform matching tests
match1 = [do_matching_action(a) for a, b  in common_objects if (a.name == b.name) and (a.ID == b.ID) and a.desc.startswith(b.desc)]

#catch some errors
bad = [do_bad(a) for a in uncommon_objects]
```